# Customizing MonoDevelop to enhance productivity and coding enjoyment

Tags: c#, asp.net, monodevelop

I'm new to C#, and although my office machine is based on windows, my netbook only has linux on it. I installed monodevelop, and so far everything is working fine.

I was just wondering if you had any tips or must dos for any person who is using monodevelop for c# / asp.net programming

**Edit**

- Feel free to recommend open or closed source tools that are useful with mono develop
- Settings I should change / modify to get a better coding experience?

Answer (score 2):

MonoDevelop requires you to do coding in most cases, as it only supports visual designer for GTK# projects. Therefore, you should try to learn ASP.NET MVC which suits the case.

If you plan to use ASP.NET WebForms, you'd better use Windows, and Visual Web Developer (Express if you cannot afford Professional and upper).

Answer (score -2):

You could use #ifdef .. to make one Project which can be compiled with Mono + VC#

Comment: This is wrong. As Mono 2.8 adds most of .NET stuffs, you can avoid #ifdef in many scenarios.